# How to re-enable Network & Sharing Center in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, services, default-settings

I have a puzzling issue. My Windows 10 machine one day a few weeks ago started to have connectivity problems. Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Steam have almost no ability to complete a web request (`Can't connect to server` message almost every time). Tor Browser and some other services work fine.

I was using Autoruns64 to look at start-up processes that may be the cause, and disabled a couple that weren't signed by Windows 10 while debugging. Sadly one of them was the service that handles the Network & Sharing center, and now Windows can't see my wireless adapters.

[Service that handles adapters disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5hKM.png)

(The `More information...` link does nothing, by the way.)

I've tried the Windows option to uninstall network device drivers and reset network settings to factory. The service did not restart.

My question is: what service is this, and how do I re-enable it? I'm pretty sure the original connectivity issue is DNS-related and I'd like to be able to change the adapter settings. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Windows Recovery -- luckily, there was exactly one restore point an hour or so before I disabled the service in question. Took about 15 minutes to restore, and now network adapters are once again seen by the OS.